# How to set specific user settings for certain Git remotes?

Tags: git, git-config

Suppose I have configuration like the following:

```
[remote "origin"]
        [..]
[branch "main"]
        [..]
[remote "alternative-origin"]
        [..]
        mirror = true
[user]
        name = My Name
        email = my@email.com
        signingkey = mysigningkey
[commit]
        gpgsign = true
```

How do I set `alternative-remote` to use another set of user settings?

Answer (score 1):

The `user` settings have nothing to do with your remote: they only affect the identity that is used in your commit messages. By the time git is communicating with a remote server, those commits already exist and have whatever user/email/etc you were using at the time.

Comment: Mmmmh I see, then I need to reformulate my question and relate it to commits instead of remotes, do you agree?

Comment: You are welcome to edit your question to more fully describe what you're trying to do. Maybe we can provide some suggestions based on that information.